# Camera Control and Form in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, form, powerapp

I have an application in which I have to record payments which are sent to the customers,

So, I have a **Form control** and a **Camera control**, I want to save both of the information into a SharePoint Document library, because of the Picture control ( it can be saved in document library. ).

I have a flow for the Camera control to save the taken picture into the document library, but I am having some issues.

1. I am unable to save both the form details and its related camera picture with the same ID into Sharepoint.
2. The Camera isn't displaying in full screen to capture the picture.
   [image]

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding, this need is more related towards PowerApps, you can go to **[this forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Community/ct-p/PowerApps1#)** which is dedicated to PowerApps to seek more professional advice.

Answer (score 1):

use [GUID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-guid) function to store with same ID and I suggest you to don't use forms if you want to customize.
Use Input fields, label and camera controls then you can easily set size and everything.